# Can't resolve a problem with closing my tooltip by onclick function

Tags: javascript, tooltip

I am trying to make a function which will close my tooltip by 'click' on the parent element which returns me this tooltip by first click on it. Need to get the closing function exclusively for tooltip parent element. Right now everything is working, but i can also close my tooltip by clicking anywhere on body element.

```
`(function () {
    function Tooltip(options) {
        if (!options) options = {};
        var self = this;
        this.tooltips;
        this.offset = 5;
        this.beforeTooltip = options.beforeTooltip;
        this.afterTooltip = options.afterTooltip;
        this.tooltipWrapper = document.createElement('div');
        this.status = false;
        this.tooltip = function (elem) {
            if (!elem.classList.contains('active')){
                if (this.status) this.remElemActive();
                if (this.beforeTooltip) this.beforeTooltip(elem);
                elem.classList.add('active');
                var coords = this.getCoords(elem);
                this.tooltipWrapper.textContent = elem.dataset.tooltip;
                this.tooltipWrapper.classList.add('active');
                this.tooltipWrapper.style.top = coords.top - (this.tooltipWrapper.offsetHeight + this.offset) + 'px';
                this.tooltipWrapper.style.left = (coords.left + coords.width / 2) - (this.tooltipWrapper.offsetWidth / 2) + 'px';
                this.status = true;
                if (this.status){
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        document.addEventListener('click', self.closeTipsBody, false);
                    }, 100)
                }
                if (this.afterTooltip) this.afterTooltip(elem)
            }else {
                elem.classList.remove('active');
            }
        };
        this.closeTipsBody = function (e) {
            if (self.tooltipWrapper === e.target || e.target.classList.contains('active')){
                return false
            }
            self.closeTips();
        };
        this.closeTips = function () {
            this.tooltipWrapper.classList.remove('active');
            this.remElemActive();
            this.status = false;
            document.removeEventListener('click', self.closeTipsBody, false)
        };
        this.remElemActive = function () {
            document.querySelector('.tooltip-js').classList.remove('active')
        };
        this.getCoords = function (elem) {
            elem = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
            return{
                top: elem.top + window.pageYOffset,
                left: elem.left + window.pageXOffset,
                width: elem.width
            }
        };
        this.init = function () {
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                this.tooltips = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip-js');
                this.tooltipWrapper.classList.add('tooltip-box');
                document.querySelector('body').appendChild(this.tooltipWrapper);
                for (var i = 0; i < this.tooltips.length; i++ ){
                    this.tooltips[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        self.tooltip(this);
                    })
                }
            }.bind(this))
        };
        this.init();
    }
    window.Tooltip = Tooltip;
})();`
```

if you need any additional info, about what do i want to get to, text me.